# qt scale items in ColumnLayout

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, scaling

I want to scale my items that they are centered have a relative height to the window.

This is my code:

```
Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    readonly property real leftPinPanelWidth: 0.1
    readonly property real rightRangePanelWidth: 0.2

    ColumnLayout {
        width: root.width
        height: root.height

        Rectangle {
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            color: "red"
            height: Math.round(root.height * 0.8)
            width: Math.round(root.width * 0.55)
        }


        Rectangle {
            color: "blue"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            height: Math.round(root.height * 0.1)
            width: Math.round(root.width * 0.55)

        }
    }
}
```

Default Window Size
[image]

Changed Height:
[image]

I don't understand why the red rectangle scales bigger than the blue one and why there is a gap between the window and the red rectangle.

I expected that both rectangles together would have always a height of 0.9 times the window size.

Comment: My QML is a bit rusty, but logically, you shouldn't set the height of the rectangles, I guess? I mean, the `ColumnLayout` is supposed to control those, right? If you want to set them yourself, use `Column` instead of `ColumnLayout`, maybe? (And if this is correct, please feel free to self-answer the question with the actual fix.)

Comment: Rule of thumb: `Column` and `Row` just puts the items one after the other. `ColumnLayout` and `RowLayout` change the relevant dimension of the item according to the layout properties, so that all items fit inside the layout.

Comment: Unrelated, for `ColumnLayout` you might want to use `anchors.fill: parent` instead of just setting `width` and `height` to be same as `root`.

Comment: Using Column works but how to I center the content when using Column instead if ColumnLayout

Comment: Don't use height/width for Layouts items, see the Note [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#details), also `width: root.width height: root.height` could be easily replaced with `anchors.fill: parent` The same for the absolute positioning, use alignment properties instead of x/y

Comment: Centering should be simple math if you are doing it "manually" without layouts. `x: (parent.width - width) / 2` or something

Comment: Ok, I migrated to "manuel" layout and calculated all the component positions myself.

Answer (score 0):

Three problems:

- Do not set the height of the ColumnLayout. By default both ColumnLayout and RowLayout evenly distribute their children. **This causes the big gap.**
- Force `spacing` to zero. The default spacing for Layout components is 10 pixels. Once you fix the first problem, then you have a small gap problem unless you set `spacing`..
- Do not set child `width` or `height` in Layout components; use `Layout.preferredWidth` or `Layout.preferredHeight`. Layout components try to resize their children. It is maddening when they override your width/height settings.

```css
ColumnLayout {
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    width: root.width
    spacing: 0

    Rectangle {
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
        Layout.preferredHeight: Math.round(root.height * 0.8)
        Layout.preferredWidth: Math.round(root.width * 0.55)
        color: "red"
    }
    Rectangle {
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
        Layout.preferredHeight: Math.round(root.height * 0.1)
        Layout.preferredWidth: Math.round(root.width * 0.55)
        color: "blue"
    }
}
```

Comment: I learned something while testing this; Layout components have a rounding error bug that causes a sub-pixel gap between elements when resizing the window (QTBUG-41216, but I see it with Qt 5.15). I never knew the cause until I noticed the gap appeared after I removed the `Math.round()` statements.